# Browse for Project Folders in Build Template TFS 2010

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, tfsbuild, build-definition

I'm adding a new argument to my custom Build template. The argument is almost identical to the default `Projects to Build` argument under `Required -> Items to Build`. It simply shows a dialog window with a list of folders under current TFS Project. I can't figure out what the type of control is. I tried `FolderBrowserDialog` but it browses the computer rather than the TFS project itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the Editor for this argument to:

```
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFileBrowserEditor, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls
```

Or

```
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFolderBrowserEditor, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls
```

[See my blog for a detailed set of steps](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2011/11/which-uieditors-are-available-for-team.html).

All of these types are `Internal`, so you can't reference them from your own code or see them easily. What you can do, is set them as `Editor` for a parameter you created in the Build Workflow. You need to specify `Typename, Assemblyname`. You can find these items in the MetaData section of your Build Template.

Add your `argument` to the workflow:
[image: Add your <code>argument</code> to the workflow]

Open the Metadata property:
[image: Open the Metadata property]

Set the editor for your property:
[image: Set the editor for your property]

---

A multi-folder select dialog is not part of the Default UI Editors. You'd have to roll your own. Either use Reflector to see how the existing ones work, or use Reflection to invoke th existing editors as part of your new editor.

It's not going to be pretty code either way, but it would work.

Comment: I don't have either of these two. It says the version is 10.0.0

Comment: They're in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls, Version=10.0.0.0`, but you can only use them through the way described in the blog, since all of these types are `internal`.

Comment: So do I have to create a project and a class first and then reference it in the Parameter type?!

Comment: You can't use these editors from your own code, unless you resort to using private reflection. Sorry.

Comment: Thats the problem, i'm not writing any code. I just need the parameter to show up when I create a build definition...

Comment: The following controls should probably allow you to do a multiselect folder or file browser. http://sdrv.ms/Y8k0lJ use `JesseHouwing.TeamFoundation.Controls.ServerFolderBrowserListEditor`or `JesseHouwing.TeamFoundation.Controls.ServerFileBrowserListEditor`. Set your parameter type to List<string> or string[].